# Karma singleRun not quitting automatically

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My karma test runner isn't automatically quitting after tests have finished, even though my config has `singleRun` set to `true` and I'm not auto-watching files, which should make the test runner run once, then quit according to the [docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html).

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
        files: [
            { pattern: 'test/*.js', watched: false }
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'static/js/src/*.js': ['browserify'],
            'test/*.js': ['browserify']
        },
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
        },
        colors: true,
        reporters: ['progress'],
        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: false
    });
};
```

When run via my gulp test command:

```
gulp.task('test', function(done) {
    new Karma({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});
```

the tests complete:

```
[09:18:38] Using gulpfile ~/static-projects/tic-tac-toe-es6/gulpfile.js
[09:18:38] Starting 'test'...
04 02 2016 09:18:40.502:INFO [framework.browserify]: bundle built
04 02 2016 09:18:40.509:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.19 server started at http://localhost:9876/
04 02 2016 09:18:40.523:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
04 02 2016 09:18:41.157:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#xIZCPzrCyB2xljZ7AAAA with id 64233425
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 9 of 9 SUCCESS (0.042 secs / 0.003 secs)
[09:18:41] Finished 'test' after 3.1 s
```

However, I have to manually quit the test runner via `Ctrl + c`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having the same issue with fresh new angular2 app made with angular cli: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030568/how-to-manage-to-exit-phantomjs-launcher-after-tests-execution

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same problem. There are various threads that elude to this problem with various fixes claimed for this:

https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma/issues/3

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1035

However, as far as I can tell this is still an issue (or maybe it's resurfaced?). The only way I've found to successfully execute karma from grunt is by spawning a child process to start karma.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('test', function(done) {
  spawn('karma',  ['start', __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'], { stdio : 'inherit' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll give that a try as soon as I can.