# How to manage to exit phantomJS launcher after tests execution?

Tags: angular, phantomjs, automated-tests, gitlab-ci

I am writing angular 2 app and trying to setup test on Gitlab CI using phantomJS launcher.
After all tests pass ok phantomJS launcher remains active forever(https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Gp8.png). How I can manage to exit after test successfully passed?

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "kibernum-dnc-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test --browsers PhantomJS",
    "testd": "ng test --browsers Chrome",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.25.5",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

and here is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
    ],
    phantomJsLauncher: {
      exitOnResourceError: true
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Command to execute test is `npm run test`.

Even with `singleRun: true` launcher stays forever.

Here is example project: https://github.com/gandra/angular-testing-demo

Steps to reprocue problem:

```
git clone https://github.com/gandra/angular-testing-demo
cd angular-testing-demo
npm install
npm run test
```

**Expected:**
Test pass ok and exit console
But this not happens :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using angular-cli, this command will solve your requirement.

```
ng test --single-run
```

or

```
ng test --watch=false
```